# ruby how to sort this Hash of Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

How can I sort the following array by :locations with the highest :local_totals from highest to lowest. On my view page, I iterate over this array and display the data exactly like I want to, but now I would like to sort them from the highest location local totals to the lowest. Is this even possible with the following format?

```
@summaries = [{:time_frame=>"Today", :locations=>["Tampa", "Atlanta", "California", "Georgia", "South Lake Union"], :local_totals=>[100000, 30000, 70000, 50000, 60000], :expenses=>[2000, 10000, 4000, 6000, 5000]}]
```

I tried to use the standard ruby sort_by method in many different ways but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Is that really an array of hash?  Doesn't look valid!

Comment: can you update your question so that the array is valid.  you should also update your question because it's a little confusing.  your array only has 1 element so it doesn't make sense to sort it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is looks like is that you actually have a hash containing some Arrays. Cleaning it up I assume it should look something like this:

`hash = {:time_frame=>"Today", :locations=>["Tampa", "Atlanta", "California", "Georgia", "South Lake Union"], :local_totals=>[10000.0, 30,000, 70000, 50000, :expenses=>[2000, 10000, 4000, 6000]}`

Assuming that is correct, you can do something like this to solve you question:

```
hash[:locations].zip(hash[:local_totals]).sort_by(&:last)
```

This assumes that the locations in the arrays match up.

I realize that by answering this I'm encouraging bad questions but it was one of those situations where I looked at it and wondered how I'd solve it then figured I might as well post my solution. :)

MINASWAN :)

Or if you want to solve it as written:

```
@summaries[0][:locations].zip(@summaries[0][:local_totals]).sort_by(&:last).reverse
```

Comment: thanks for the response, are you saying it would look like this. @summaries[:locations].zip(@summaries[:local_totals]).sort_by(&:last)Im getting a nil object error

Comment: No, you need the [0] since you've made it an array with a single entry being a hash. So the [0] is referencing the hash, and the :locations and :local_totals are keys of your hash.